# Apache Airflow\ DAG's with different requirements.txt

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to run different dags with different requirements.txt files, I've noticed that each task can be wrapped using

`PythonVirtualenvOperator`

. Are there any other solutions that at are more suitable for this task?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend reading this blog post which answers your question and offers some other ideas along the way: https://medium.com/bluecore-engineering/were-all-using-airflow-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it-a56f14cb0753

In short, you can use KubernetesPodOperator to express arbitrary environments as docker images and have Airflow act as a Kubernetes orchestrator.

Comment: thanks, I"ve looked at this article and it seems like a more complex solution. For now I'm looking at: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7d08cacfbbabe95cc147771332125ab806f2ee14/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L169                                                                              did you implement any of the above solutions?

Comment: Kubernetes is definitely a more complex solution. For the shop that I'm at we ended up implementing that since we felt the extra complexity justified the number of jobs and job types we wanted to run. I haven't worked with PythonVirtualenvOperator so I can't comment too much on that; but you could also consider DockerOperator which should bring less complexity than Kubernetes while still bringing many of the advantages.

Comment: Is this answer and these comments still the best solution. I was hoping to use airflow  to orchestrate all of my python scripts, but the idea of a single requirements.txt file for all the scripts is not workable.